# Ubuntu server 15.04: remote access MySql

Tags: server, mysql

I install the MySQL from the Ubuntu server CD (15.04). When installation is finished, I found that the configure files under `/etc/MySQL/`, such as `my.cnf` and `MySQL.cnf` are all empty.

So I want to access my database from other terminals, I did the following job:

1. Created a user for host `%` with all privileges;
2. Made firewall utw  allowing MySQL;
3. Insert a line in the my.cnf with: bind-address = 0.0.0.0;
4. Restarted the MySQL service.

It has no effect. Remote connections are still denied.

I checked the variables in MySQL, the bind_address variable shows binding with 127.0.0.1. And the netstat command shows that port 3306 is only bound with 127.0.0.1.
I don't know why the configure information in `my.cnf` has no effect?

The configuration file shows below:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 15.04 the MySQL Server configure file is in:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

You can find `bind-address` here. Comment it (by inserting `#` at the start of it), and restart your MySQL Server using:

```
service mysql restart
```

Then you can access your MysqlServer from other computer. If you can't, perhaps you need grant some right to the user.

You can see MySQL Server bind-address using:

```
netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

So you know whether the configuration has taken effect.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking in my.cnf which no longer contains the bind-address

Answer (score 0):

Line 59 of `my.cnf` says:

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

You'll probably need to change this instead of inserting a new line at the end of the file.

That being said, I recommend, if possible, using SSH with port forwarding to access MySQL remotely instead of opening up your MySQL port to the world.